# Size of buffer pointed to by char* returned from field_buffer

Tags: c++, ncurses

So I am trying to work with the `<form.h>` library provided by `<ncurses>`

I am reading [this man page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_field_buffer.3x.html) that tells me of the function:

`char *field_buffer(const FIELD *field, int buffer);`

The return type is a pointer to `char *`. On the end of this pointer, I suspect, is a c-style array containing the `chars` I want to access.
Now I can use this function cautiously and try to not overstep when reading out the data (it returns all chars saved in a field, so I suppose not looping past the field size is a cautious approach). But is there no way for me to know the size of the buffer pointer to by `char *`?

I only now this way to read out the data:

```
char *ptr = fiel_buffer(someField, 0);
size_t dontKnow = 100; //if I had the underlying array arr I would do dontKnow = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]
for (size_t i = 0; i < dontKnow; i++)
   std::cout << ptr[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: @Borgleader actually yes, I tried it out, they seem to be null terminated. I did not think of that :-) Thank you very much. Is that so obvious that it does not need to be mentioned in the man page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not explicitly stated, but since there's no pointer to a length-parameter allowing the library to return the string-length as a side-effect, you have the C convention of null-terminated strings.

The manpage does say this:

> The function field_buffer returns a pointer  to  the  contents  of  the
> given *numbered buffer*:
>
> - The  buffer contents always have the same length, and are padded
>   with trailing spaces as needed to  ensure  this  length  is  the
>   same.
> - The buffer contents are set with **`set_field_buffer`**, or as a  side
>   effect of any editing operations on the corresponding field.

and

> The  function  **`set_max_field`** sets the maximum size for a dynamic field.

(dynamic fields are mentioned in another manpage, [form_field_info](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_field_info.3x.html)).

Actually that "always the same length" applies to the number of columns used for the field.  If you have stored a multibyte string (UTF-8), the number of bytes is not necessarily the same for each buffer.  The source for [`field_buffer`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/f21b57e07039e11e902d06eb1513f89c49836b0e/form/frm_driver.c#L4864) is the place to read for details like that.

The original SVr4 manpages were less informative — see [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36880/field-buffer-3curses.html) for example (and the tutorials in the reference manuals not much better).

Comment: thank you for your reply! Please understand that I was not criticizing the page in any way, I was asking out of ignorance. Thank you for guiding me to the `field_buffer` page. I have tried `dynamic_field_info ` and that seems to be what I am looking for.